# Region D of $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ described by $x=\int_0^\alpha e^{-\tau}\cos\beta(\tau) d\tau$, $y=\int_0^\alpha e^{-\tau}\sin\beta(\tau) d\tau$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
x=\int_0^\alpha e^{-\tau}\cos\beta(\tau) d\tau \qquad   \\
y=\int_0^\alpha e^{-\tau}\sin\beta(\tau) d\tau \\
\end{cases}
$$
where $\beta$ is a function such that the integrals in the RHS exist. For $\alpha, \beta\in[0,1]$, is it possible to determine the region D described in $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$?

I think that the described region is a circle. Maybe isn't it so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $\text{R}(e^{i\beta\tau})=cos(\beta\tau),\text{I}(e^{i\beta\tau})=sin(\beta\tau)$ and then integrate to see what it is and i think it will have closed form as $\alpha,\beta\in[0,1]$